# Google maps not supported in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have an asp.net-mvc app and I'm using Google api for displaying a map. The map displays properly when using google chrome:

[image]

but when I switch from chrome to internet explorer 8, it shows the following error:

> You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps
>   JavaScript API. Consider changing your browser.Learn more

and the result is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I know I can upgrade the browser and the error won't appear, but can I change my js or html code to get rid of this error?

And what can I do to make the api support this version of internet explorer?

Comment: `You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API` seems obvious that it's Google Maps JS API that doesn't support that ancient browser - so, unless you buy google ...

Comment: U can't do anything to the api to support this version of IE

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, it means i only have one option and the option is to upgrade the browser?

Comment: `yes i know i can upgrade the browser` ... only if you're running Vista or 7 ... what version of windows are you running? (why use IE at all - there's never an excuse) - your options are - use another browser

Comment: i am using window 7 @JaromandaX

Comment: well, IE9 will run ... hope you're on 7SP1 - that way you can get a marginally better IE11 ... seriously, do you have friends? do they let you run IE? they're not friends :p

Comment: actually this app is on our server (windows server 2007) and we have many restrictions on that server, and we don't even have chrome or mozilla firefox